# Protect a "private" class member from modifications

Tags: javascript, oop, object

i use getter for only see the my private property but when i use get, i can change my object too.
what shall i do??

```
function Circle(radius = 1) {

    let number = radius;
    this.draw = ()=> number;

    let defaultLocation = {x: 0 , y: 0};

    Object.defineProperty(this,"defaultLocation",{
        get(){ return defaultLocation},

        // set(value) {
        //     if (!value.x || !value.y)
        //         throw new Error('invalid location.');
        //     defaultLocation = value;
        // }
    })
}
const another = new Circle(2);
another.defaultLocation.x = 100 ;
console.log(another);
console.log(another.defaultLocation);
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have private properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i write another.defaultLocation.z = 100 , this change my object so i wite this correct code.

```
function Circle(radius = 1) {
    let number = radius;
    this.draw = ()=> number;

    let defaultLocation = {x: 0 , y: 0};

    defaultLocation = {};
    Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"x", {
        enumerable: true,
        value: 0,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"y", {
        enumerable: true,
        value: 0,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this,'defaultLocation',{
        get(){
            let key =Object.keys(defaultLocation);
            let keyJoin = key.join('');
            if (keyJoin ==="xy")
                return defaultLocation;
            else
                throw new Error('invalid key')
        },
    });
}

const another = new Circle(2);
another.defaultLocation.z = 100 ;
console.log(another);
console.log(another.defaultLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object `defaultLocation` which has 2 properties, `x` and `y`. Default objects are mutable. Using a getter to return an object don't makes the object non-mutable.

You have to create an object with "immutable" properties and return that object.

```
let defaultLocation = {};
Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"x", {
    value: 0,
});
Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"y", {
    value: 0,
});

Object.defineProperty(this,"defaultLocation",{
    get(){ return defaultLocation}
});
```

This way, you cannot change `defaultLocation.x` and `defaultLocation.y` values with an assignment like `defaultLocation.x = 100;`. With this, `defaultLocation.x` will still return `0`.

If you want to modify the properties, you can do so by calling `Object.defineProperty` over `defaultLocation` again or by using another variable and modifying that variable:

```
// Method 1 (more verbose and less performant)
Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"x", {
    configurable: true,
    value: 0,
});
console.log(defaultLocation.x);
Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"x", {
    configurable: true,
    value: 10,
});
console.log(defaultLocation.x);

// Method 2
let _x = 0;
Object.defineProperty(defaultLocation,"x", {
    get: () => _x,
});
console.log(defaultLocation.x);
_x = 10;
console.log(defaultLocation.x);
```

Comment: "static properties" is misleading - in OOP "static" means something different. You mean *immutable* properties or constant ones.

Comment: this will prevent changing `defaultLocation` from inside the object as well.

Comment: @georg I've not added the `configurable: false` property. You can still modify it with another `Object.defineProperty` call. Also you can use getters again. Added a clarification for this.

Comment: Forgot that `configurable` defaults to `false`. Damn me.

Comment: if i use ```defualtLocation.z =1``` this change my object again and im dont want to change my object

Comment: @KavehKarami Then call `Object.freeze(defualtLocation)` after defining all its properties. This will prevent any change to its properties. The hard way wil be using `Proxy`, but that requires a manual, so better get a tutorial if you get to the point of using `Proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid modifications would be to return a *copy* of the member:

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this._center = {x: 0, y: 0};
    }

    get center() {
        return {...this._center}
    }
}



const a = new Circle(2);
a.center.x = 100 ;
console.log(a.center);
```

If you want more "protection" you can also place "private" variables in a closure:

```
function Circle(radius) {
    let _center = {x: 0, y: 0};
    let _radius = radius;

    return new class {
        get center() {
            return {..._center}
        }
    }()
}
```

but this hardly makes sense. Encapsulation (public/private members) is not about "securing" your class, it's about preventing the users of the class from breaking things accidentally.

If you just want a "constant" object, which no one, including your class, is allowed to change, consider `Object.freeze`:

```
const defaultPosition = Object.freeze({x: 0, y: 0});
defaultPosition.x = 100;
defaultPosition.z = 200;
console.log(defaultPosition); // {0, 0}
```

Comment: ... and then on `a._center.x = 42`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet: looks fine to me. If you decide to access the private API and deliberately break my object, be my guest. I have no means to stop you anyways. The above code is to protect good faith users from breaking things _accidentaly_.